# Is it worthy to create a one to one relationship?

Tags: sql

I have a table A that has many fields that define A but also a lot of fields that define something that A can be, but not always. I'm thinking about splitting this entity in two: a reduced A entity containing only the fields pertaining to A and a B entity cointaining the fields that pertain to A when it "also assumes the form of B".

(To explain better: "A" is a table called Mission and "B" would be a table called Monster. It happens that, in my domain, a mission can be many things, and sometimes it is a monster. There are many fields that define a monster, so the original Mission table is huge).

That said, I'm debating myself whether I should or not create this Monster table. Should I just accept my fairly big Mission table or should I go ahead and create a 1:1 relationship? The Joins would be executed quite frequently, and I'm a bit worried about this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are going to need the "Monster" each time when you load a "Mission" then most likely the separate tables and the required join won't make sense. But with regards to performance the only truth comes from measuring. So create a schema for each scenario, fill it with the expected amount of data and then test your most common use cases.

Comment: If the tables A and B afterwards have the same number of columns you would not save any memory space and just add the complexity of a join. If it is performance critical you should probably try to avoid that join. And also ask yourself what the actual disadvantage of one single table would be. The number of coulmns is hardly an argument I guess.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I will study if I can isolate Monster whenever I need it otherwise I'll leave the table as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for 3 tables (not two):

1. Table for the missions,
2. Table for the Monster types (including for each type all the relevant properties),
3. Table for the monster instances (i.e. when you need an actual monster); this table will hold a reference to the Monster type table that you can use whenever you need the Monster's properties.

In this way, your need for HUGE tables/space would be drastically reduced.

Comment: Thank you! So far I don't need to differenciate between Monster Types, but that would be a good motivation to come up with a separate Monster table. So far I decided to leave as it is :)

Comment: OK. Still, if you believe that my answer was helpful, you may consider up-voting it. By the way, different monster types could be, for instance, a monster that didn't eat a person, the same monster that eat one person, etc,, where each could have different properties (like the eagerness with which it would try to catch persons to eat).

Comment: Oh, yeah! Those are cool ideas! Thank you! And I upvoted your answer :)

Comment: You are welcome. Now, if you've gone that far (up-voting), there is a small "V" to the left of my answer that I would appreciate if you also click on it.